# Is Basic Auth for EWS going to be disabled soon?

Tags: exchangewebservices, exchange-basicauth

Microsoft seems to want to start disabling Basic Auth for Exchange Online and mentioned ending support for EWS protocol
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-february-2021-update/ba-p/2111904

We're using `Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.2.2` library to get emails from EWS inbox like that:

```
var service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);
var findResults = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(int.MaxValue));
```

Is this going to be disabled in the near future? Should we change the way we access emails?

Comment: Ultimately yes. But for now you are safe. They did the same for github also.

Comment: Yes you should migrate to using oAuth as soon as you can for a number of reasons